# Android UI issues, button selection

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android and I've just learned about activities and I decided to create a few.

and my MainActivity.java is,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WidgetIntro.class));

            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class));

                    Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
                    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            startActivity(new   Intent(MainActivity.this, Sms.class));

                            Button d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
                            d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    startActivity(new   Intent(MainActivity.this, Call.class));

                                    Button e = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.button3);
                                    e.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notes.class));

                                            Button f = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
                                            f.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cbdata.class));

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Though this has no error and I've created some text to toast for every button, when I install my application on my phone I'm able to access buttons only in the order I've numbered them, that is for 'Location Widget' button my button id is button1 so except for this button I'm able to select any other buttons and once I've selected this button I can only select button 2 but not any other button, why does this happen?

My activity_main.xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:text="About Us" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="Note Remainder" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Alarm" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="SMS" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Call" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:text="Location Widget" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Hello User, Welcome to Mobile location Info! You Choose from the following options :"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Save my locations" />

</RelativeLayout>

        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: This is Quite a usual problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined each buttons onClick listener inside the onClick listener of the previous button.  Therefore, each button after the first one only has an assigned onClick listener when you click the previous button.

Instead, do this:

```
Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WidgetIntro.class));
    }
});

Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class));
   }
});
```

A tip.  In general, when you see more than about 3 levels of closing braces, like this then you know there is a problem:

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly if the problem is only being able to access the buttons but the order you numbered, I see this is because you have embed each button into the other, to correct this problem let each button listener be a main member method of the onCreate method that eay each has equal access from the UI. Hope that helped :)